# html efficient retractable table columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I am trying to create a dynamic html table with retractable columns.
In real case, I can have 20 columns per header and up to 400 values.
I would like to present the data like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|    |            Header 1          | Header 2 | Header 3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|val1| col1.1 | col1.2 |...| col1.x | col 2.1  | col 3.1  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|val2| col1.1 | col1.2 |...| col1.x | col 2.1  | col 3.1  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
 ...
-----------------------------------------------------------
|valx| col1.1 | col1.2 |...| col1.x | col 2.1  | col 3.1  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|foot| foot1.1| foot1.2|...| foot1.x| foot2.1  | foot3.1  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want the ability to click on and colx.1, expand or show all the columns under the same header and collapse (or hide) other columns for other headers. 
From the table above clicking on any col2.1 cell would then change the table to :

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|    | Header 1 |            Header 2          | Header 3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|val1| col 1.1  | col2.1 | col2.2 |...| col2.x | col 3.1  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|val2| col 1.1  | col2.1 | col2.2 |...| col2.x | col 3.1  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
 ...
-----------------------------------------------------------
|valx| col 1.1  | col2.1 | col2.2 |...| col2.x | col 3.1  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|foot| foot1.1  | foot2.1| foot2.2|...| foot2.x| foot3.1  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried to do something like:
use hideable class on all td elements that can be shown/hidden
and to something like:

```
var rows = $('tr');
rows.find('th:eq(1), td:eq(1)').on('click', function() {
    $('.hideable').toggle()
});
```

I also need to change the colspan of headers and footers accordingly with

```
('th#foot1.1').attr('colspan',1)
```

The above solution works but is very inefficient and does not seem very clean.

Added simplified jsFiddle sample [jsfiddle.net/yrMsX](http://jsfiddle.net/yrMsX/). The idea would be not to have header 1 and 2 expanded at the same time.

Is there a better, more effective way to achieve this?

Comment: PS: performances have greatly improved after using latest jquery version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5fv3/) hope is what you were looking for.

Basically you should focus on this:

- give the header and its sub cols same class
- set ***colspan*** attribute for those headers you want to toggle
- set a ***data-fullcol*** attribute to each header to keep track of their maximum *colspan*
- bind to **click event** *only those columns with **colspan** attribute*
- give a ***first* class** to those columns you want to *stay visible*
- on click event hide all columns whose class doesn't equal the one of the clicked header and haven't also a *first* class
- sett all other headers *colspan* to 1
- **toggle** all the columns with same class as the header you clicked one
- to **toggle** the header's *colspan* set *colspan* to ***(data-fullcol - colspan +1)***

**NB : this will only work if headers have single classes, if you want to give 'em more than one class, consider saving the 'important class' in a specific attribute like *data-class***

Comment: This looks exactly like what I am looking for, thanks! Let me apply it and test it against my case to see if this works correctly before I accept the answer.

Comment: Works like a treat on my actual data table. Only thing I added was $(function(){
    $('td:not(.first):not(.classic)').hide()
    $('th:not(.classic)').attr('colspan',1)
});

Comment: just to load the page with one column expanded!